# Cannot create a copy of a database with a new name by restoring from backup: "the database is in use"

Tags: sql-server, database, backup, database-backups, sql-server-2017

I have two sets of databases for my different testing environments (internal qa and uat). I'm trying to bring qa up to date by restoring it from the latest uat backups. I encountered an issue with the qa DBs getting stuck in "restoring" mode and ended up deleting them, so I'm trying to create a brand new database now by restoring from the UAT backup and changing the name, but it keep failing.

> Restore database
>
> Source: device > latestUATbackup.bak
>
> Destination: database > change name from UAT.Web to Dev.Web
>
> Files > check off Relocate all files to folder
>
> Options: Close existing connections to destination database

"Restore of database Dev.Web failed. Access could not be obtained because the database is in use"

I tried taking UAT.Web offline but then it fails with the error "UAT.Web cannot be opened because it is offline"

Why would it matter if the database is in use when I'm using a backup? What do I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can't restore a database that is in use because the restore would put it in an inconsistent state.  You need to disconnect all active connections (including all SSMS query windows and other applications) from the database in order to restore it.  If it already exists make sure to check "Overwrite existing database" on the Options tab of the restore window.

On a side note, up to you but I would recommend not using a '.' in the database name.  It can get confusing when using fully qualified object names that include the database.

Comment: I don't understand though why it would affect the in-use database, since I'm restoring from a backup, and creating a new database, not altering the existing one

Comment: Does Dev.Web already exist on the server instance when you're trying to restore?

Comment: No. It did but I deleted it after getting it stuck in "restoring" state, and I have also checked the option to overwrite any existing databases anyway

Comment: As long as Dev.Web does not exist already, you changed the destination database to Dev.Web, and the physical file names don't already exist, then it should restore without problem.  Can you post a screenshot of the restore window that is giving you the error?

Comment: I think I found the issue. Under Options, Tail-Log backup > Take tail-log backup before restore > Leave source database in the restoring state was checked off, so I think this is why it was complaining that the source database was in use

Comment: That would explain why your original restore left your database in the Restoring... state, but not why you would get a Database In Use error if the destination database does not exist on the instance.  It sounds like you left that option checked, the db was stuck Restoring, then you tried to restore again before deleting and got the error.  After you deleted, you should have no problem restoring.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Options and tick the 'Close existing connections to destination database' option before restoring.

Comment: I've been doing that. Doesn't fix it. The issue isn't the destination database, it's the database that I'm using the backup of. I ran a script to kill all connections to UAT.Web and it still fails